# Can i find out when app permissions change?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, permissions

I have an app which requires the use of location services, but attempts to fetch data every minute. This means that even if the user allows location services after a second, it'll be another 59 before it refreshes. Is it possible to know when app permissions changed?

Comment: Blast out some code please, really.

Comment: Why don't you use the method: -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status

Comment: @Zhang You should probably make that an answer.

Comment: @Zhang i'd select that as the correct answer if you made it one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK fine, I'll make it an answer lol.

Don't take my word for it though, I encourage you to try it out and see if it does what you want first.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    // -----------------------------------------
    // Available authorization status are:
    //
    // kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
    // kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied
    // kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
    // kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted
    // -----------------------------------------

    if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatus...)
    {
        // do something here
    }        
}
```

It's a CLLocationManager delegate so you need to create a CLLocationManager object then set its delegate to self and make your view controller conform to the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol:

```
// .h file
@interface MyClass <...,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,....>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

// in the .m file
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    locationManager.delegate = self
}
```